# Use custom pipe with dynamic image url in image tag ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-pipe

I need to set authentication headers to images called from image tag ( `<img>` ). So I created a pipe using `ionic g pipe secureimages`.

This creates the pipe to intercept http interceptor where I set the header.Below is my custom pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * Generated class for the SecureImagesPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'secureimages',
})
export class SecureImagesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
            .map(val => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(val)));
    }
}
```

and on interceptor,

```
const headers = req.headers
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
  .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const reqClone = req.clone({
  headers
});
return next.handle(reqClone);
```

And in image tag,

```
<img  [attr.src]='{{this.imageURL}} | secureimages | async'/>
```

But it throws compile errors. **But if I use static url, it works.**

How dynamic image url can be defined in image tag so that it will use the provided pipe.

Comment: But on doing that, app failed on compile time. The error is Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ this.imageURL | secureimages | async }}] in ng:///AppModule/UserIdPage.html@7:39 ("> <ion-col col-12 class="profile-picture-container"> <img class="profile-picture" [ERROR ->][attr.src]="{{ this.imageURL | secureimages | async }}"/> </ion-col> </ion-row> "): ng:///AppModule/UserIdPage.html@7:39

Answer (score 0):

You should not use curly braces when you are binding attributes with brackets `[]`.

```
<img  [attr.src]=" this.imageURL | secureimages  | async "/>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But on doing that, app failed on compile time. The error is Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{ this.imageURL | secureimages  | async }}] in ng:///AppModule/UserIdPage.html@7:39 (">
        <ion-col col-12 class="profile-picture-container">
          <img class="profile-picture" [ERROR ->][attr.src]="{{ this.imageURL | secureimages  | async }}"/>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
"): ng:///AppModule/UserIdPage.html@7:39

Comment: My mistake :/ You should remove curly braces if you bind attributes with brackets.

Comment: Removed the curly braces and getting a weird issue :- ion-dev.js?v=3.2.1:157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of null
    at ObservableStrategy.dispose (common.js:5582)
    at AsyncPipe._dispose (common.js:5741)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:5694)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (UserIdPage.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
...

Comment: can you try this : `[attr.src]=" (this.imageURL | secureimages)  | async "` If this won't work, then I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It didn't work either. Gave the same issue as given in the previous comment. Thanks for spending your valuable time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and got the answer. As contributors here said, the pipes should be inside the braces. Also the dynamic image variable should be initialised. In my case, the variable was type casted but not initialised. On initialisation, it works. Thanks.